# When LdCom is used instead of COM?

Tags: communication, autosar, automotive

Communication in AUTOSAR can take two major paths : com and ldcom. I understand that ldcom is more efficient version of com (By removing most COM features). But are there any general rules/Criterion that can help decide to stick with one of them?

[image]

Comment: There are situations when the PDUs are large (let's say 60kb). Those PDUs can be then transmitted using LdCom. The criteria will be the real time constraints. (an example: the data should be end to end protected and available on the bus in 20ms)

Answer (score 1):

If you are reimplementing all the features of Com within your SWC(s), then you are definitely using LdCom for the wrong reasons.

And if your SWCs now depend also too much on the definition of the network (e.g. you have to change your SWC always as soon as the network description changes), then you also using LdCom for the wrong reasons.

Comment: i totally get & agree with the first point but could you please provide a more detailed example of the second point? because if the network parameters change, i will be changing "Com" configurations as well..